# New AMD Catalyst driver update screwed things up. Where can I find and older version?

Tags: windows-7, drivers, graphics-card, amd-radeon

Today I decided that I was going to update my AMD Catalyst divers, this end up being a bad idea. The installation failed and I seem to not be able to run the latest vision of Catalyst Software Suite 14.9. I have a Radeon HD 6700 and my OS is widows 7 home premium 64bit.

I have tried uninstalling Catalyst and everything that goes with it, then update Windows, then reinstalling.

I have tried going to programs the clicking on Catalyst and repairing.

Now I want to downgrade back to and older Catalyst Software Suite. Where can I find and older version?

Comment: And your specific question for all of us to answer?

Comment: I have not been able to get a older vision.

Comment: Have you checked the manufactures web site for you card and used their driver?

Comment: http://support.amd.com/en-us/download/desktop?os=Windows%207%20-%2064 this side yes I did not find any thing on topic.

Comment: What is the vendor name on the card?

Comment: its a amd graphics card so amd?

Comment: Is this a retail video card that you added to your system or a chipset built into the motherboard?  If it is the latter, it is not uncommon for the Catalyst drivers from AMD to not work.  Go to the computer manufacturer's web site and download the OEM version of the drivers.

Comment: it is a retail video card, but I just found and installed vision 14.7 from http://support.amd.com/en-us/kb-articles/Pages/latest-catalyst-windows-beta.aspx and it seams to work. strange that the recommended vision did not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Download [Display Driver Uninstaller](http://www.wagnardmobile.com/DDU/) and clean your system from the old drivers.

Then download any older version from [AMD](http://support.amd.com/en-us/download/desktop/previous?os=Windows%207%20-%2064).